# Is "will just need to [verb]" grammatical?

Tags: grammar

Consider this sentence on an official form:

> To change the arrangement, you will just need to fill up a new
>   application form.

For some reason, the phrase "you will just need to" sounds awkward.

Is it correct/grammatical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's grammatical. It means "you only need to" or "you merely need to". It's also quite colloquial, something you hear often. But "fill up" isn't heard that often; more likely it will be "fill in" or "fill out".

Answer (score 2):

It's correct, but you don't really need the 'just' part. 'Only' might suit better here.

> To get to the shop, you just need to run around the corner.

For comparison, the above would work fine.

Perhaps try

> To change the arrangement, you will only need to fill **in** a new application form.

Comment: Why does _only_ "suit better" than _just_?

Comment: It flows better off the tongue! Same meaning, just a friendlier tone.

Comment: Ah, I must have different tongue flow and tone detectors.